# How can I configure url in rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables package?

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-10

I have a laravel project that use livewire. I've been upgrading from livewire 2 to 3 version.
I also use the rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables package but it seems that the url request that use this package is not right.
My project is served on http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/example/public

```
       GET http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/livewire/livewire.js?id=c4077c56 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

       GET http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables/core.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)   
        
       GET http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables/thirdparty.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
        
       GET http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables/core.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

       GET http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables/thirdparty.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I found that I have to change the asset_url livewire config variable (because it was no longer supported on livewire 3) and to customize it I added this to my routes/web.php :

```php
    Livewire::setScriptRoute(function ($handle) {
        return Route::get('/example/public/livewire/livewire.js', $handle);
    });
```

So this error disappeared but not the others related to laravel-livewire-tables.

The config file for this package is like this :

```php
<?php

return [
    /**
     * Options: tailwind | bootstrap-4 | bootstrap-5.
     */
    'theme' => 'tailwind',

    /**
     * Filter Frontend Asset Options
     */

    /**
     * Cache Rappasoft Frontend Assets
     */
    'cache_assets' => false,

    /**
     * Enable or Disable automatic injection of core assets
     */
    'inject_core_assets_enabled' => true,

    /**
     * Enable or Disable automatic injection of third-party assets
     */
    'inject_third_party_assets_enabled' => true,

    /**
     * Enable Blade Directives (Not required if automatically injecting or using bundler approaches)
     */
    'enable_blade_directives ' => false,

    /**
     * Filter Default Configuration Options
     *
     * */

    /**
     * Configuration options for DateFilter
     */
    'dateFilter' => [
        'defaultConfig' => [
            'format' => 'Y-m-d',
            'pillFormat' => 'd M Y', // Used to display in the Filter Pills
        ],
    ],

    /**
     * Configuration options for DateTimeFilter
     */
    'dateTimeFilter' => [
        'defaultConfig' => [
            'format' => 'Y-m-d\TH:i',
            'pillFormat' => 'd M Y - H:i', // Used to display in the Filter Pills
        ],
    ],

    /**
     * Configuration options for DateRangeFilter
     */
    'dateRange' => [
        'defaultOptions' => [],
        'defaultConfig' => [
            'allowInput' => true,   // Allow manual input of dates
            'altFormat' => 'F j, Y', // Date format that will be displayed once selected
            'ariaDateFormat' => 'F j, Y', // An aria-friendly date format
            'dateFormat' => 'Y-m-d', // Date format that will be received by the filter
            'earliestDate' => null, // The earliest acceptable date
            'latestDate' => null, // The latest acceptable date
        ],
    ],

    /**
     * Configuration options for NumberRangeFilter
     */
    'numberRange' => [
        'defaultOptions' => [
            'min' => 0, // The default start value
            'max' => 100, // The default end value
        ],
        'defaultConfig' => [
            'minRange' => 0, // The minimum possible value
            'maxRange' => 100, // The maximum possible value
            'suffix' => '', // A suffix to append to the values when displayed
        ],
    ],

];
```

I don't know how and where configure it, do you have any idea?

Comment: facing the same issue, if i serve my app in non-root uri, like http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/example/ 

GET http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables/thirdparty.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

it completely ignores the /example